# Porque me marca error String index out of range: -1?

Tags: java, array, string

```
String Nombre="armando";




    for (int i = 6; i <Nombre.length(); i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Nombre.length(); j++) {

        char n =Nombre.charAt(i);//Se supone que en esta linea esta el error

        char matriz[][] = new char [n][n];

            if (j == i) {
                matriz[i][j] =n ;



            }

                    System.out.print(matriz[i][j] +"  " );
        }
                System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    }
```

Esto es el codigo en donde marca error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia `for (int i = 6; i <Nombre.length(); i--)` por `for (int i = Nombre.length() - 1; i > -1; i--)`

Recuerda que los indices empiezan desde cero hasta tamaño -1 y que cuando el ciclo va restando debes asegurar no caer en negativos i >-1 (el cero sería el primer caracter)